# getting an error while running Bootstrap 4 with Angular 6 Application

Tags: angular, npm, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

I have installed Bootstrap 4 using Angular CLI, but I am getting an error after I run the Application.

I have updated `angular.json` file as follows:

```
"styles": 
    [
        "src/styles.css",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    ]
```

I have added `@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';` the the  `style.css` file.

But still I am getting the error:

```
ERROR in multi ./src/styles.css ../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/user/Projects/A4/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' in '/Users/user/Projects/A4/demo'
```

Comment: Try this  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css".

Comment: just remove it from the `styles` array in `angular.json`. You've added `bootstrap` in `style.css`. No need to do this twice

Answer (score 0):

Remove front '../'.

```
"styles": 
     [
       "src/styles.css",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
             ],
```

Comment: I did but Still I am facing same problem